# I'm trying to change date formats from yyyy-mm-dd to dd-mm-yyyy in talend tmap please help me?

Tags: type-conversion, talend, tmap

I'm trying to change date formats in Talend from yyyy-mm-dd to dd-mm-yyyy I'm trying to parsing but it is not working.

Comment: Adding snippets will help understand, what you are trying to do, and what attempt was made.

Comment: what you have tried so far?

Comment: I have tried this code TalendDate.parseDate("dd/MM/yyyy", TalendDate.formatDate("dd/MM/yyyy", TalendDate.parseDate("MM/dd/yyyy","10/20/2015")))

Comment: And what happened when you did that?  Please put the code and the error messages / stacktraces into the question.  Also, please fix the tags.  I can't see how this question is about both Java and JavaScript.  Only include the tag for the language that is **relevant** to your problem.

Comment: Does this help? https://help.talend.com/r/6K8Ti_j8LkR03kjthAW6fg/lLZrYifwbkypcqPLMK~IJA

Comment: What is the datatype of your input field ? What is the expected datatype of your output field ?

Answer (score 3):

This should work if your input column type is String and output column type is Date. Check the data types of column.
TalendDate.parseDate("dd/MM/yyyy", TalendDate.formatDate("dd/MM/yyyy", TalendDate.parseDate("MM/dd/yyyy","10/20/2015")))